# One to many join creating duplicates despite CASE statement

Tags: sql, join, duplicates

I tried searching but probably lack the language to find a similar post, so here's my basic issue
(`SQL Server 2016`)...

I have a query that identifies unique customer encounters (`1 line per 1 transaction`). I am then trying to pull in the items that customer bought from another table. If they bought multiple items, the joining table lists that transaction multiple times with a field called "Line" to indicate a ranking of those items.

Table 2:

```
Transaction--Line--Item

1000--1--Staples

1000--2--Stapler

1001--1--Paper
```

I want the end result in my query to be:
Table 1:

```
Customer--Transaction--Item1--Item2

John Doe--1000--Staples--Stapler

Jane Smith--1001--Paper--NULL
```

I am currently trying to do this with a `CASE` statement in my `SELECT`:

```
SELECT Table1.Customer,

Table1.Transaction,

CASE    WHEN Table2.LINE = 1 THEN Table2.Item
                ELSE NULL
                END as Item1

CASE    WHEN Table2.LINE = 2 THEN Table2.Item
                ELSE NULL
                END as Item2

FROM Table1 left outer join Table2 on Table1.transaction=Table2.transaction
```

This produces the right results, except that the one to many join is placing these on duplicate rows

```
John Doe--1000--Staples--NULL

John Doe--1000--NULL--Stapler

Jane Smith--10001--Paper--NULL
```

I want `John Doe` all on one row. Other than running two separate update statements after the initial query, I don't know how to get the result I want. Help?

(apologies for the lousy formatting)

Answer (score 0):

Below should work. assuming there will be at least on entry in Table2

```
SELECT Table1.Customer,
Table1.Transaction,
t1.Item AS Item1,
t2.Item as Item2
FROM Table1 
INNER JOIN Table2 t1
   on c.transactions=t1.tid
left outer join Table2 t2 
   on Table1.transaction=t2.transaction AND t2.Line=2
where t1.line=1
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. That doesn't appear to be working, as the WHERE clause is excluding anything from the lookup that isn't Line = 1. I should probably add that I'm simplifying a much more complicated query. There are at least 7 other left joins happening but this is the only one where I have a one transaction to multiple results issue.

Comment: i think other option is go with some thing like below
'(Select Item from Table2 where transaction = table.transaction and 
Line=1)  END as item1,

(Select Item from Table2 where transaction = table.transaction and Line=2)  END as item2,'